# Java: how to print Guava Table overriding toString methods of contained objects

Tags: java, guava

I have a Guava Table that I would like to dump to a log. However the RowKey and ColumnKey types are closed to me, and their toString() methods of the key types are based on Apache ToStringBuilder so the result is annoyingly verbose.

What is the simplest way to dump this table, but outputting the keys as I desire?

Comment: Which implementation are you using?

Comment: @Rcordoval -- Thanks. Implementation of what?

Comment: Please paste the line where you create the table. check this [examples](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-table)

Comment: Loop through the table's `cellSet` and append to a `StringBuilder` directly.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman -- that's what I'm trying to avoid: re-implementing table's toString() logic.

Comment: @kevinclone you almost certainly can't avoid it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Thanks. I suppose if what I wanted were possible (like temporarily monkey-patching the types for the table.toString() call) then Java wouldn't be Java.

Comment: @Rcordval: Table<...> table = HashBasedTable.create();